# ASP.NET Application In Multiple Datacenters - Best Architecture?

Tags: asp.net, iis, architecture

I've traditionally followed the 'one app, one server' architecture for most of the ASP.NET/SQL Server applications I've worked on. I mean that loosely, having used multiple servers with a load balancer, etc. But they have all been in the same datacenter.

However, recently, a requirement has come up to scope an application which will support users in the US, China, and Russia. Performance will be fairly critical, so what is the most sensible way to architect such an application so it performs well in all these areas?

The options I've come up with are:

- Use one single data center (ie: don't host in multiple places around the world). Deliver static content over a CDN, but database and ASP.NET site will be hosted in one place (eg: US). This seems like performance may still be an issue though.
- Use multiple data centers, and have multiple versions of the application. Eg: ru.myapp.com, us.myapp.com, ch.myapp.com with their own code/databases/etc. This will work, but things like reporting, management, etc would need to be done in each application, which seems like the least efficient approach.
- Use a different architecture - but I'm not familiar with alternatives. Is it possible to architect in such as way that you have one single application and database that works across multiple data centers (like a load balanced environment, but on a larger scale).

Does anyone have any experience in the best way to handle this?

Comment: Option 2 is a fairly common approach. Depending on what you're reporting on and whether this functionality is bespoke or an OOTB product, many of these are able to combine data from various sources (distributed databases in your case). This may not be an option for you however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your front end servers can work across data centers same as they work within a single data center. There are some differences though - Load balancer does not usually work cross colo. Do you would have to use geo DNS to route people to nearest data center and then use a load balancer within that data center.

The main issue that comes up is use of shared resources, such as DB or a web service such as authentication web service. If you really need a single DB, then one architecture is to have a single master, but multiple read slaves spread across different data centers. The reads are then NOT paying any penalty for going cross colo. The writes do have to go cross colo and thus pay the latency penalty. This works for most sites where writes are much less numerous than reads and where write performance can be 1-2 seconds slower than read and still be counted as acceptable. e.g. take a movie ticket booking site. The reads are overwhelmingly more than writes.

The cross colo performance can be dramatically improved through the following choices
1. Minimize the number of round trips. e.g. do all writes over a single transaction rather than doing multiple writes through multiple calls to DB. i.e. use batch queries, stored procedures, batch remote call etc. 
2. Use optimistic write/eventual consistency if possible. e.g. say you are recording the time a user logged in. You can very well make it asynchronous, where the time is eventually recorded. Though there are scenarios where the eventual consistency is not acceptable.